Custom cursor_class does not work with dictionary attribute - LoggingCursor
I am using mysql-connector-python==9.0.0 and need a custom cursor class. By default, I used:
cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)

This returns data as a dictionary instead of a tuple (which is the default) as it was necessary for my app. The problem is when I use:
cursor = db.cursor(cursor_class=LoggingCursor, dictionary=True)

The dictionary attribute is ignored, and data is returned as a tuple.
Here is my LoggingCursor class:
class LoggingCursor(CMySQLCursor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(*args)
        super(LoggingCursor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.executed_statements: list[str] = []

    def execute(self, operation, params=(), multi=False):
        result = super(LoggingCursor, self).execute(operation, params, multi)
        self.executed_statements.append(self.statement)
        return result

    def executemany(self, operation, seq_params):
        result = super(LoggingCursor, self).executemany(operation, seq_params)
        for _ in seq_params:
            self.executed_statements.append(self.statement)
        return result

    @property
    def all_executed_statements(self):
        return self.executed_statements

Note that I needed to use the cursor C extension because if I used mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor (which is the default class), I got this error:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Cursor class needs to be a subclass of cursor_cext.CMySQLCursor 

So, how can I return the result as a dictionary while using a custom cursor class?

mysql_connector has CMySQLCursorDict class. You need to use this instead to be able to return the result as dict.
class LoggingCursor(CMySQLCursorDict):
      pass 

cursor = db.cursor(cursor_class=LoggingCursor)

I added the complete code in this gist.
